# BigQuery load and transfer jobs files limit

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

BigQuery [quota for load and transfer jobs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas#load_jobs) is as follows:

```
| Limit                                              | Default          | Notes                                                                                             |   |   |
|----------------------------------------------------|------------------|---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|---|---|
| Maximum number of source URIs in job configuration | 10,000 URIs      | A job configuration can have up to 10,000 source URIs.                                            |   |   |
| Maximum number of files per load job               | 10,000,000 files | A load job can have up to 10 million total files, including all files matching all wildcard URIs. |   |   |
```

I though I understood the description, ie, we can have up to 10k URIs in the configuration, but since they can have wildcards that expand to files, we can have up to 10,000k files for each run.

However, I configured a [Transfer Job](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/cloud-storage-transfer) that reads CSVs from a bucket and writes to a table. It does it every 15 mins:

```
Destination table: my_table
Cloud Storage URI: gs://my-bucket/*/*/*/*/*/*
Write preference: APPEND
File format: CSV
```

And, even though the files count is under `10,000,000 files` I get this error:

```
Transfer Run limits exceeded. Max size: 15.00 TB. Max file count: 10000. Found: size = 154202147028 B (0.14 TB) ; file count = 67639.
```

**What I cannot understand is why it's limiting to 10k files, if the quota is 10,000K.**

As a side note, the reason I'm using `Cloud Storage URI: gs://my-bucket/*/*/*/*/*/*` is because data is Hive partitioned by five levels, and cloud transfer can't handle it, so I'm expanding to get the files under the last partitions for all folders.

Comment: Do you want to export or load data? From where? Can you provide more detail on what you do and not only the error?

Comment: edited with more info.
it loads from a bucket on gcp, csv files, to a table in bigquery. I'm trying to understand the limits of the loading job. The bucket gets really a ton of files every hour and if bigquery transfer scheduled job can't handle the number of files I'll need to move to another tool, probably spark.

Comment: Why do you use a transfer job and not a load job? You lose me!! Do you want to load the files in GCS in BigQuery? Do you want to transfer the files in GCS to another GCS? Do you want to transfer BigQuery data to another project or region? Can you clarify your flow?

Comment: " I configured a Transfer Job that reads CSVs from a bucket and writes to a table. It does it every 15 mins.
So gcp -> bigquery.
I can use load jobs. They have the same quotas transfer jobs have AFAIK. Transfer jobs are easier to set up and to schedule.

Comment: Maybe an error somewhere. Either in the documentation or in the service. You should open a case to the Google Support